Validating SharePoint List's Date Column For NULL Values Throughs Exceptions
I have a SharePoint List that has a column named 'Agreement Review Date'.
I have created a Power Automate Workflow that send an email alert to business managers when the Agreement Review date is today.
However, some of the records contain an empty 'Agreement Review Date'. This is triggering an exception in the 'Apply to each' section only to the records which don't have an empty 'Agreement Renew Date'.

In order to resolve that I tried to send the email alert only for the records that have an 'Agreement Renew Date' and I tried the following conditional statement in Power Automate 'Condition' ---> Parameters
formatDateTime(items('Apply_to_each')?['AgreementReviewDate'],'yyyy-MM-dd') IS NOT EQUAL TO null.


When I checked the next failed attempt, there is an error in the 'Condition section'. Please refer to the below error message.

InvalidTemplate
Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Condition' at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'formatDateTime' expects its first parameter to be of type string. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#formatdatetime for usage details.'.
I am unable to find the root cause of these error messages.
Regards,
Chiranthaka

A friend showed me a different solution for the issue.
It's about using the 'Filter Query' in the 'Get items' action.
The query string used is:
AgreementReviewDate ne null

It's just neglect the NULL values in the Agreement Review Date column.
@skin thank you for your help.

Yes, that is another way.  Sometimes it's nice to see all of the data however and see how it's processed but yes, always another way and likely quicker overall.

You’re trying to format the null values, that’s never going to work.
If you need to check for a valid date then you can add a coalesce to default a date to something way back in the past that you know you'll never hit, so the left side of your condition should be ...
formatDateTime(coalesce(items('Apply_to_each')?['AgreementReviewDate'], parseDateTime('01-01-1970')), 'yyyy-MM-dd')

... and then the right hand side of the IS EQUAL TO should be your formatDateTime of the current days date.
That also negates the need for the second condition that checks for nulls.  The coalesce does that for you.
Bottom line, the call to formatDateTime must contain a valid value, it can't be null, that approach above gets you over that.
This is how your condition should look after applying those changes ...

Left Side = formatDateTime(coalesce(items('Apply_to_each')?['AgreementReviewDate'], parseDateTime('01-01-1970')), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
Right Side = formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')

Thanks for the reply. However, I'm a little bit confused, the first row of the AND is to compare the 'AgreementReviewDate' with UTCNOW(). Before comparing them with each other, I format the date format to 'yyyy-MM-dd'. The second row is to check the 'AgreementReviewDate' is NULL and I haven't used any formatting to do that. I can't understand where I have tried to format the NULL values.

You haven't tried to use null values, it's that some of the values you're running formatDateTime over are null. That's not going to work, hence why using coalesce is a way to overcome the issue. Also your screenshot doesn't line up with the expression you provided so I put two and two together. I'll update my answer with how your condition should look
